# Nuke the [damage] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

The tag [damage](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/damage) is too vague, and people use it for very different things. Please block it.

Comment: is it used for anything else than IT hardware damage questions? should it be renamed to hardware-damage instead?

Comment: There's [hardware-failure] already.

Comment: so a synonym or a retag? (15 letters)

Comment: I don't know what's the most appropriate solution, but [hardware-failure] is at least clearer than [damage].

Comment: Both should be burned IMO. It should be enough to tag with the device in question, without worrying about a [damage] or [hardware-failure] tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[damage](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/damage) has received a critical hit.

Comment: could we add the status-completed tag...?

Comment: Forgot we might be using [meta-tag:status-planned] to work out what needs doing.  Fixed now.  Also added a vague wiki excerpt to the tag.

Comment: lol. but don't tags get deleted by the system automatically? if there are no questions with it...?

Comment: That's what I'm hoping, but just in case...